# How can I solve tooltip and popover conflicts between DevExpress MVC and Bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, devexpress-mvc

When I use following codes I get this error; "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function"

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
})
```

I remove DevExpress javascripts for check, It works;

```
@Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.HtmlEditor },
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView },
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.PivotGrid },
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors },
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Chart },
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Report },
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Scheduler },
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.TreeList },
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Spreadsheet },
new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.SpellChecker }
    )
```

I try this to solve conflict but I got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noConflict' of undefined"

```
$(function () {
    var bootstrapTooltip = $.fn.tooltip.noConflict();
    $.fn.bstooltip = bootstrapTooltip;
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').bstooltip();
})
```

Do you have any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from DevExpress;

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T249836#answers